# How can I see the version number of a GNOME Shell extension?

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I have installed several GNOME Shell extensions, some from extensions.gnome.org , and some using APT. I would like to see which version of a GNOME Shell extension is installed.

If I open the "Extensions" app by running `gnome-extensions-app`, this is what I see:

[image: Screenshot]

There does not seem to be a way to view the version number of a GNOME Shell extension like "Blur my Shell".

Answer (score 4):

The version numbers are displayed in the app "Extensions" (launched by running `gnome-extensions-app`), next to the titles of the extensions. It's easy to miss:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Using `Extension Manager` alongside each installed app there is a small right pointing chevron at the far right beyond the slider switch.

Click on that and it will open a further information screen detailing, amongst other things, the Version number.

Click again on the (now) down pointing chevron to close the information details.

`Extension Manager` can be installed using the following command:

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager`

[reference](https://itsfoss.com/extension-manager/)

[image]

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, OP isn't interested in the version of GNOME, but in the version(s) of any installed extensions ;)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Thanks for that, I misread the OPs question. Have now provided a corrected answer using `Extension Manager`.